# How do I improve ventilation above my cathedral ceiling?

Tags: attic, ventilation

I live in San Bernardino County in southern California.  Half of my house has a cathedral ceiling, and the other half is traditional attic. The attic has two gable vents, one at each end of the house; there are no eave vents.

How can I improve ventilation in this type of attic to remove heat. Can I insulate between the cathedral ceiling and the roof deck?

Answer (score 0):

If the gable vents are passive, the easiest and most effective thing to do is add [active ventilation](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/catalog/servlet/Search?keyword=gable%20vent%20fan&Ns=None&Ntpr=1&Ntpc=1&selectedCatgry=SEARCH%2bALL) at one of the gable vents.  That alone can reduce the attic temperature from 150+ °F to 100 °F, or closer to the outside air temperature.

There are even solar powered ventilation fans which naturally work harder when there is more sun.

As for your question about insulating between the attic and the ceiling, we would need to see a blueprint or photo of the situation to determine what might work and how effective it would be.